# Using an Async method in a Azure Fuction Servicebus trigger

Tags: c#, string, azure, task, azure-functions

I'm making a Project using a queue storage, blob storage and a Azure Function with a queue trigger. It consists in anytime the queue receive a message, takes a picture with the same name in a blob, later using a FaceApi makes an analysis sending   a ServiceBus Topic in a Json. the program is async.

```
public static async Task<string> MakeAnalysisRequestAsync()
string valor = "";
            const string subscriptionKey = "yoursubsciptionkey";

         
            const string uriBase =
                "https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            // Request headers.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
                "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

            // Request parameters. A third optional parameter is "details".
            string requestParameters = "returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false" +
                "&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses," +
                "emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise";

            // Assemble the URI for the REST API Call.
            string uri = uriBase + "?" + requestParameters;

            HttpResponseMessage response;

            //forearch element in yourqueue, search in blob storage and make an analysis
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(
"yourstorage",
"connectionstorage"), true);

            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("yourstorage");



            // Create the queue client
            CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

            // Retrieve a reference to a queue
            CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("yourqueue");

            // Get the next message
            CloudQueueMessage retrievedMessage = await queue.GetMessageAsync();

            string prueba = retrievedMessage.AsString;
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(prueba);

            var uriblob = blockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            byte[] imageBytesuri = webClient.DownloadData(uriblob);


            using (ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(imageBytesuri))
            {
               
                content.Headers.ContentType =
                    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

                // Execute the REST API call.
                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

                // Get the JSON response.
                string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                valor = contentString;
   
            }
            return valor;
}
```

it work correctly, for instance if there is a message in a queue with name Darren.png it Will return the face analysis of the picture Darren.png in a blob storage, like this

```
[{"faceId":"45 345345435","faceRectangle":{"top":84,"left":98,"width":83,"height":83},"faceAttributes":{"smile":1.0,"headPose":{"pitch":-11.3,"roll":8.4,"yaw":-9.4},"gender":"male","age":48.0,"facialHair":{"moustache":0.1,"beard":0.1,"sideburns":0.1},"glasses":"NoGlasses","emotion":{"anger":0.0,"contempt":0.0,"disgust":0.0,"fear":0.0,"happiness":1.0,"neutral":0.0,"sadness":0.0,"surprise":0.0},"blur":{"blurLevel":"low","value":0.0},"exposure":{"exposureLevel":"overExposure","value":0.83},"noise":{"noiseLevel":"low","value":0.08},"makeup":{"eyeMakeup":false,"lipMakeup":false},"accessories":[],"occlusion":{"foreheadOccluded":false,"eyeOccluded":false,"mouthOccluded":false},"hair":{"bald":0.13,"invisible":false,"hairColor":[{"color":"brown","confidence":1.0},{"color":"red","confidence":0.66},{"color":"blond","confidence":0.25},{"color":"black","confidence":0.16},{"color":"gray","confidence":0.13},{"color":"other","confidence":0.03}]}}}]
```

Now, I created an AzureFunction with queue trigger and load the analysis program "faceApiCorregido".

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([QueueTrigger("yourqueue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
        {
           string messageBody =  Funciones.MakeAnalysisRequestAsync().ToString();

            //Task<string> messageBody2 =  Funciones.MakeAnalysisRequestAsync();
            //string messageBody1 = await messageBody.GetResult();
            log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
            const string ServiceBusConnectionString = "yourconnectionstring";
            const string TopicName = "topicfoto";
            ITopicClient topicClient;
            topicClient = new TopicClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, TopicName);

            // Create a new message to send to the topic
            //string messageBody =  FaceApiLibreriaCoreFoto.Funciones.MakeAnalysisRequestAsync().ToString();
            
           // string messageBody = FaceApiCorregido.Funciones.MakeAnalysisRequestAsync().ToString(); 
            var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));

            // Write the body of the message to the console
            Console.WriteLine($"Sending message: {messageBody}");

            // Send the message to the topic
             topicClient.SendAsync(message);
            
            
        }
```

But it not work it, that it's i need a string instead of  a Task. I have tried different ways for fix it but it don't work, for instance if I write

```
string messageBody =  Funciones.MakeAnalysisRequestAsync().ToString();
```

it will return something like that

```
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.String,FaceApiCorregido.Funciones+<MakeAnalysisRequestAsync>d__1]
```

I also tried with getResult().getAwaiter() but I have errors. And finally I tried to make my AzureFunction Async but also gave me an error like that System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. FaceApiCorregido: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I know this is a common problem and there are a lot of information for fix it, but I don't know how.

Comment: Can you show the async Function code?

Comment: Sorry, I just did it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the function async.

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task Run([QueueTrigger("yourqueue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
    string messageBody = await Funciones.MakeAnalysisRequestAsync();

    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to run synchronously just call

```
string messageBody =  Funciones.MakeAnalysisRequestAsync().Result;
```

if async:

```
string messageBody =  await Funciones.MakeAnalysisRequestAsync();
```

Async methods do not directly returns the result. They return a Task instead and you have to wait for it to finish either by the await keyword which will release current thread and resume once the task is finished or by just calling result which will block current execution until result is available.

Comment: Thank for yor advice, but in both cases it return the same issue System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.). FaceApiCorregido: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. However, when I write string messageBody =  Funciones.MakeAnalysisRequestAsync().ToString();. it send System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.String,FaceApiCorregido.Funciones+<MakeAnalysisRequestAsync>d__1].

Comment: when you do `Funciones.MakeAnalysisRequestAsync().ToString();` you apply ToString on the task, not on the result. This leads to `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1+AsyncStateMachineBox1[System.String,FaceApiCorregido.Funciones+<MakeAnalysisRequestAsync>d__1].`

Comment: Your problem is inside your Async function, not in the way you call it. Either of my suggestion will work.

Comment: In this case, I don't find out the problem, let me explain I use the async method in a console Project(FaceApiCorregido), and work without problems.

Comment: when looking at your code, it seems obvious there is somthing you did not understand with Task. you start them but never wait for the result. For instance you have to wait for `topic.SendAsync(message)`with `.Wait()` or `await`. Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-en/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: Yes I don't really understand, in fact all I did it is to change the program MakeAnalysisrequest of this page https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/csharp, but I only  made it async and I haven't any problema in the console Project. But, thank you so much for the information.

Comment: @AntonioManuelManceraHevilla Your console app has the same code as what you have in MakeAnalysisRequestAsync method. That is working because you don't have a bug in that method. Your bug is in the azure function i.e Run method. In MakeAnalysisRequestAsync, do you notice how you use "await" keyword for async methods? You are not doing that in you Run method. In fact in your run method you attempt to use .ToString(). That is incorrect. I recommend reading a tutorial on async await. Try [this](https://www.dotnetperls.com/async).